# DB2 - find and compare the lentgh of the value in a table field

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to find and compare the length of a field value in table.

```
Table1
Id Name 
1  abcd
2  xyz
3  Y
```

I am trying to find the name with length more than 3. The result should have only  record with id 1

I tried `LEN`. Its not in db2 . i tried `length` . Its giving the field length ,not the actaul length of the value in that field.

```
select id,name,LENGTH(name) as namelength  from table1 
group by id,name having LENGTH(name)>3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your field is probably defined as `CHAR`, which pads the remaining length with spaces.  You can `TRIM` this off, and you'll get what you're looking for:

```
SELECT id,name,LENGTH(TRIM(name)) AS namelength
FROM table1 
GROUP BY id,name
HAVING LENGTH(TRIM(name)) > 3
```

This assumes Linux/Unix/Windows DB2.  If you're on the Mainframe z/OS DB2, then you'll use `RTRIM` instead of `TRIM`.

Comment: I usually use RTRIM, i.e. leaving out leading spaces.

Comment: LTRIM for leading spaces, RTRIM for trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the condition in where clause itself,

select id,name,LENGTH(name) as namelength from table1 where LENGTH(name)>3