# determine DB2 text string length

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to find out how to write an SQL statement that will grab fields where the string is not 12 characters long. I only want to grab the string if they are 10 characters.

What function can do this in DB2?

I figured it would be something like this, but I can't find anything on it.
`select * from table where not length(fieldName, 12)`

Comment: Wait - do you want to grab _rows_ where the data a **specific** column ('field') contains is 10 characters long, or do you want to grab **unknown** columns for all rows, where all values in the column (or the name of the column) is 10 characters long?

Comment: I want to grab all rows from a id number column. Some id numbers are 10 digits long, some are 9, and some are 12. I want all except the 12 digit numbers.

Comment: Is the column actually a numeric type, or you're using numeric characters in the Id?  If it's actually a numeric column, just do simple numeric comparison.  If it's a string containing digits, please don't have leading zeros...

Comment: It's a text field. Sorry. It just happens to be that they are all numeric for the time being. But yes, the field is text type.

Comment: Well, a natual-key id field, text, that (currently) contains only digits is fine - the expectation is that at some point you _may_ have other characters.  I just don't recommend allowing leading zeros, as your users may not realize their importance.  In the general case, david's answer should be the way to go, however.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This will grab records with strings (in the fieldName column) that are 10 characters long:

```
 select * from table where length(fieldName)=10
```

Comment: Also check this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0705nair/ - determining string length might be tricky sometimes.

Answer (score 35):

From similar question [DB2 - find and compare the lentgh of the value in a table field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726724/db2-find-and-compare-the-lentgh-of-the-value-in-a-table-field) - add RTRIM since LENGTH will return length of column definition. This should be correct:

```
select * from table where length(RTRIM(fieldName))=10
```

UPDATE 27.5.2019: maybe on older db2 versions the LENGTH function returned the length of column definition. On db2 10.5 I have tried the function and it returns data length, not column definition length:

```
select fieldname
, length(fieldName) len_only
, length(RTRIM(fieldName)) len_rtrim
from (values (cast('1234567890  ' as varchar(30)) )) 
as tab(fieldName)

FIELDNAME                      LEN_ONLY    LEN_RTRIM
------------------------------ ----------- -----------
1234567890                              12          10
```

One can test this by using this term:

```
where length(fieldName)!=length(rtrim(fieldName))
```

Comment: This does the trick! It gets the actual length of the string like the OP asked and not the length of the column.

Comment: Thanks, nice hint!

Comment: This is not correct. It is going to return the field length, not the character length

Answer (score -1):

Mostly we write below statement
select * from table where length(ltrim(rtrim(field)))=10;

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before answering any question. Thanks.

Comment: the above is accepted answer is not correct. This worked for me